# is there any way to get datapoints /datalabels always for the area and line chart using ngx area/line chart properties without hovering?

Tags: d3.js, charts, chart.js

Iam trying to get the datalabels/datapoints  always for the area and  line chart using ngx area and line chart properties without hovering. but unable to find the solution ,every where it is written js using plugins.for pie chart we have labelFormattng like that  is there any way for area  and line chart?

Need to get datalabels for area and line chart  using ngx properties without hovering.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.